# Inject dependencies into views with roboguice

Tags: android, guice, roboguice

Activity fields:

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {
    @InjectView(R.id.my_view)
    protected MyView myView;

    @Inject
    private MyDependency myDependency;

    // onCreate etc
}
```

View fields:

```
public class MyView extends FrameLayout {
    @Inject
    private MyDependency myDependency;

    // constructors etc
}
```

The problem is: both `myView` and `myDependency` are injected into the activity, but the `myDependency` is not injected into the view. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are instantiated by the Android framework, not by Roboguice.  You can use [Injector.injectMembers](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#injectMembers%28java.lang.Object%29) to inject the view's members, but I'd try to avoid Guice dependencies from inside the View.

Comment: Isn't it weird that Roboguice's `@InjectView` does not inject dependencies automatically with injector? Nevertheless, when I call `injectMembers` manually, it works indeed. Why should I avoid this?

Comment: It's not weird because the behaviour of the view should not depend on whether the associated activity has an `@InjectView` for it.  The view should work anywhere it is specified in XML.